# Glitch or bad design during booting on Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, startup

After enabling FileVault with recent T2 firmware patch the loading bar looks weird like its missing pre-cached image:

[image]

I replaced default `Mojave.heic` with a test image and gray "transparent" area kept test image framed while the rest of the screen remains black after system switched to user scale. Setting `Display -> Scaled` back to `Default`  returning smooth booting. Is this a design issue or missing cache?

macOS 10.14.5 (18F203)

Comment: Is the Brightness slider set all the way up in Displays settings?

Comment: @IconDaemon Almost on the max.

Comment: Bump it down to half then restart to see if this shadow grey goes away.

Comment: @IconDaemon 10%, 20%, 40% Brightness - no changes.

Answer (score 2):

The firmware controls that phase of screen rendering, not the OS.

My understanding is that by design, the full graphics library mode isn’t enabled intentionally. Whether people label it a glitch or feature (or good / bad design) might be wading into opinion territory. I don’t know the back story on this, but it’s plausible an engineer figured the risk (or manager figured the priority/cost) to embedding more code into firmware when weighed against a “let’s be pretty about everything” design goal. We can all agree on what shipped though by inspecting the screen during updates.

We are not seeing any problem with the update at work so haven’t reported this as a problem to Apple.

Comment: So it is the same behavior on 10.14.6

Comment: Same on Catalina

Comment: We’re not seeing any problem this causes @charlie137 so I’ve edited my post. I hope my answer helps you decide what to do.

Comment: I was hoping this is not intentional since that would be way too depressing. But apparently things are *that* bad since nothing's really changed. With freebsd extremely laptop-friendly now and "`kext` fiasco" - thats a no brainer)